# idevicediagnostics marketing name with 9th generation iPad

Tags: libimobiledevice

I noticed idevicediagnostics (version 1.3.0) returns value "iPad" as marketing name for 9th generation iPad, instead of "iPad (9th generation)".

Tested with command : idevicediagnostics mobilegestalt marketing-name

The value is correct with older iPad versions : iPad (8th generation), iPad (7th generation), ...

Is there another way to retrieve a complete marketing name?

Thanks!